# Как вывести результат из Терминала в файл

Tags: c, printf

```
// работа с файлами с помощью FILE fopen, fclose
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 1000

int main()
{
    int age, weight;
    char name[50]; // массив символов
    printf("Пожалуйста введите ваше имя: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Введите ваш возраст: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Введите ваш вес: ");
    scanf("%d", &weight);
    printf("Выведем нашу информацию:\n");
    printf("Ваше имя %s, Ваш возраст %d лет, Ваш вес - %d кг.\n", name, age, weight);

    char str[LEN]
    // следующую строчку printf я хочу записать в файл с введёнными данными
    char nameUser[LEN] = printf("Ваше имя %s, Ваш возраст %d лет, Ваш вес - %d кг.\n", name, age, weight);
    FILE *file_ptr;
    file_ptr = fopen("new_file.txt", "w");

    if(file_ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Файл new_file.txt успешно создан!\n");
        printf("---Считываем данные из файла:\n\n");
        while(fgets(str, LEN, file_ptr))
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", str);
        printf("\n---Считывание данных из файла завершено!\n");
        fputs(nameUser, file_ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Не удалось создать либо открыть файл new_file.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Доброго времени суток!
Я хочу чтобы строка типа printf с данными введенными в терминале (я работаю в Ubuntu 16.04) записывались в файл эти данные, что у меня не правильно листинг файла смотрите выше, пишу на Си. Спасибо заранее за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Формируйте строку при помощи `sprintf`:

```
char nameUser[LEN];
sprintf(nameUser, "Ваше имя %s, Ваш возраст %d лет, Ваш вес - %d кг.\n", name, age, weight);
```

или, можно писать в файл минуя временную переменную, при помощи `fprintf()`:

```
fprintf(file_ptr, "Ваше имя %s, Ваш возраст %d лет, Ваш вес - %d кг.\n", name, age, weight);
```

Так же, не забывайте вызывать `fclose()`, после окончания работы с файлом.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ на вопрос, а как вызвать fclose() я новичок в Си

Comment: @Сергей RTFM! `fclose(file_ptr)`

Answer (score 1):

При запуске Вы используете `./a.out <args>`, либо `./ИМЯ_ИСПОЛНЯЕМОГО_ФАЙЛА <args>`

Просто используйте такой формат запуска `./a.out >1.txt <args>`

Этот вариант всё, что должно было быть выведено с помощью `printf` поместит в файл `1.txt` (если файла нет, то он будет создан; иначе -- перезаписан)

Если интересует дозапись в конец, то используйте `>>1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Вам не кажется, что между утверждением:

> Я хочу чтобы строка .. записывалась в файл

и кодом:

```
fgets(str, LEN, file_ptr)
```

есть некоторое противоречие ? Что Вы пытаетесь ПРОЧИТАТЬ из только что созданного, а потому - пустого файла ?!

Comment: это я взял из урока, я уже удалил в if(file_ptr != NULL) всё и вызвал только fclose(file_ptr), также выше по коду использую fprintf